# nc tool not showing any output on busybox for localhost

Tags: netcat, busybox, nc

Any ideas why `nc` is not showing anything when ran on a busybox based container image?
The problem appears when trying to connect to port on `127.0.0.1`/`localhost`.

```
/app # nc -v 127.0.0.1 12345
/app # nc -v localhost 12345
/app # nc
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-08-01 15:14:44 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen
...
```

What I would expect is to see if `nc` has connected or not. On normal Ubuntu the command outputs successful or unsuccessful connections like below. On busybox I don't know what happened because nothing is outputted.
[image]

Comment: What is running on port 12345? What sort of output do you expect to see?

Comment: Many  commands in busybox are a pale imitation of the full  command/tool they mimic. So I'm not quite sure what you expected to see.

Comment: @larsks I added explanation what I expect: basically I want to simply know if it connected or not?

Comment: It looks to me like busybox `nc` returns an error code if it fails to connect. So `nc localhost 12345 || echo FAILED` is maybe what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux/Unix programs don't saying anything unless some error occurred.
This is because same programs are often also used for scripting.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy
Additionally BusyBox by design is quite and tries to avoid large texts.

But you can check for error code that the program returned with `$?` command.

```
$ busybox httpd -p 8080
$ busybox nc 127.0.0.1 8081
nc: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
$ echo $?
1
$ busybox nc 127.0.0.1 8080
^C
$ echo $?
130
```

Here I started httpd on port 8080. Then executed the nc but it failed with error code 1. Again started nc on 8080 port and it was successful and didn't tell anything. But I interrupted it so the exit code was 130: